# can i add a read.me file to an existing project on github?

Tags: github

I pushed up the beginnings of a project to github without adding a read.me file. is it possible for me to add a read.me file to the already existing project?

Comment: It's just a file. Git would be a pretty useless tool if you couldn't add files to a repository.

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase your question as "How do I..."

Comment: I don't think this question deserves to be downvoted quite so much, it might be a bit of an obvious question for those of us who poke around in Github on a daily basis, but for someone who is new to it, it isn't an obvious answer.

Comment: It's an obvious answer if you try something first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as Github cares a read.me is simply another file in the project. You are free to add or amend it whenever you desire.

Comment: makes perfect sense. Thanks!